# sql delete all rows after where

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible in sql to delete since one row until the end of the table ?
for instance :

```
delete from mytable where oneDate ='2017-06-06';
```

and since this row delete all following rows?

Comment: Use `>=` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Tables are inherently unsorted, so no, it's not possible. You can use a range in your where clause though to reach the same effect.

Comment: If oracle you can use rowid. Get the rowid of the target row and then delete all the rows having rowid greater than the target row

Comment: Depends on how you define 'after', if for example your date is the start point, then as pointed out use >=.  If your table has an auto-increment key, then it would be a case of all keys higher than the identified row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.
Example:

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [table.ID]>=50
```

Assuming the table has 100 records it would delete from 50 to 100, keeping the first 50. Same with dates and having into consideration some criteria to filter from some specific point on (in my example, the ID).